# Is there any well defined $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, that is not the limit of any sequence of polynomials?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions, polynomials

Can all functions, $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be given as the limit of a sequence of polynomials $\left(p_i\right)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with real coefficients? Is there a particular function that categorically cannot? The convergence may be any type, pointwise, uniform, etc. and the function may be as discontinuous and pathological as you want.

Of course, well-behaved elementary functions like $\sin x$ and $\exp x$ can be given as Taylor Series while discontinuous functions such as $\mathrm{sgn} x$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ can be given as Fourier Series, which in turn can be formed of Taylor Series but is there some exception?

I think this should be a relatively clear-cut question and I've got a feeling the answer is an obvious yes but I really don't know.

Regards, Jam.

Comment: $f(x)=1$ when $x$ is rational and $0$ when irrational is well-defined and not any such limit :)

Comment: @ZelosMalum Hey Zelos, I vaguely recall hearing about that function on the site before. Is there a proof of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Here is a nonconstructive proof: There are $|\mathbb R|^{|\mathbb R|}=\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ functions $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. However, there are only $|\mathbb R|$ finite tuples of real numbers, hence only $|\mathbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}$ polynomials.

That means that there are only $|\mathbb R|^{|\mathbb N|}=\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ sequences of polynomials. Hence there are at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ functions $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that can be written as the limit of a sequence of polynomials with real coefficients.

Since $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}>2^{\aleph_0}$ by Cantor's theorem, there is at least one function $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that cannot be written as the limit of a sequence of polynomials with real coefficients. In fact, almost all functions can't be written as the limit of a sequence of polynomials with real coefficients.

Comment: Wahey. Not only did you give a good answer, it was one I understood too (and I wasn't expecting that). Thanks. Do you think we can easily construct one of the functions that can't be expressed as a sequence?

Comment: Nice answer, BUT you need also to address the fact that one deals with more than one potential type of convergence. Your argument fails for example if one would allow for $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ different types of convergences ;)

Comment: @Jam I was thinking about it, and it seems that the example by ZelosMalum ($f(x)$ is $1$ if $x$ is rational, $0$ if $x$ is irrational) is indeed such an example. This function is known as the Dirichlet function. However, I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: @N.S. I assume a finite definition of convergence. In that case, there are at most $\aleph_0$ of them.

Comment: @N.S. and wythagoras I'm not too familiar with alternative definitions of convergence so yeah, I was mainly thinking about finite forms.

Comment: Yea, I assumed that finite type of convergence is assumed, but I wanted to emphasize that this answer makes this assumption. BTW: it is easy to define uncountably many types of weak type convergence at once ;)

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note is that $f$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of polynomials iff $f$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions. This follows from the Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Another thing to note is that by Baire, every pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ is continuous on a dense $G_{\delta}$ subset of $\mathbb R.$ Thus $\chi_{\mathbb Q}$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you are looking for, but remember that when dealing with various types of convergence you should work with **nets** not sequences.

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be any function.

Define $A$ to be the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb R$. For each $\alpha \in A$ define $p_\alpha$ to be any polynomial which coincides with $f(x)$ on $\alpha$ [you can use Lagrange interpolation here].

Then $(p_\alpha)_\alpha$ is a net of polynomials, which converges on finite sets (hence poinwise) to $f(x)$.

Comment: Note that the OP specifically talks about "sequences" of functions; this should really be a comment, rather than an answer.